# Is it possible to wholly simulate the source code for firmware locally?

Tags: emulation, qemu, firmware

At my work we are trying to debug firmware code locally as if one could debug it like typical software.  Right now this is done through dongles and ran on the firmware itself.  We have looked into QEMU but our firmware has some proprietary device models such that, if we customized the QEMU device models, would cause licensing issues due to QEMU's GPL license.

When I have looked around for alternatives to QEMU, there were about three kinds of emulation software that had licenses free enough such that device model customization would not be an issue:

1. [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/)
2. [bhyve](https://bhyve.org/)
3. [box86](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86)

However, none of these seem to fulfill a use case similar to QEMU, OpenStack is more for cloud applications, box86 is more for games, and bhyve doesn't even have a download link. And much of the [other alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/qemu/) I found either had the same licensing issues as QEMU, did not have an open source license, or did not deal in firmware simulation.

This leads me to ask: Is there a tool out there that makes it possible to wholly simulate the source code for firmware locally?

Comment: You seem to be confused between drivers (which is software that runs on the hardware and talks to it -- QEMU has none of this) and device models (which is software that emulates a piece of real hardware -- QEMU has  lots of this). Modelling your hardware and having an open source model of it places you under no obligation to make your driver sources open.

Comment: Yes I am.  Updated question accordingly.

Comment: It still seems confused. Your firmware doesn't have device models, it has drivers. The license of the firmware (or other guest software) doesn't affect the license of an emulated device, or vice-versa.